# BuildNavMesh is too slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    NavMeshSurface.BuildNavMesh();
```

I want to do "Bake" of NavMesh dynamically. My game is like Minecraft.
I move the MOB around the world. Player can place blocks. So, if I do **BuildNavMesh()** I will be able to "Bake" NavMesh with new blocks.

Blocks is placed by the player. And every time player puts a block, I do BuildNavMesh(). Players can jump on them. Player can also destroy those blocks.

As I mentioned earlier, I do not know what to do other than that.
I can only write the above code.

```
    NavMeshSurface.BuildNavMesh();
```

The best result I want is to use NavMesh to dynamically change the MOB's range of motion.

Comment: I dont have much experience making minecraft kinda games, but I think nav mesh is overkill for it. Maybe you should find another way of mob movement?

Comment: Is there a good system other than NavMesh? It seems to be difficult to realize this with NavMesh.

Comment: Minecraft does not use a NavMesh, it uses the block data in the world: every solid block can be stood upon. All you need to know is: "is this block solid?" "is there enough space above it?" and "can I jump up/down to here?"

Comment: It seems [someone solved this by leveraging NavMeshBuilder.UpdateNavMeshDataAsync](https://ckempke.github.io/Blog/blog/runtime_navmesh/)

Answer (score 2):

My navmesh was also building extremely slow. 2 things that really helped were:

1. play around with the tile size on the NavMeshSurface component, the smaller the faster it will build but it has some tradeoffs.
2. remove unnecessary layers from you NavMeshSurface component. And this was really the biggest issue. I had the default layer and ui layers in there which caused a big lag, removing them almost instantly rebuilds the navmesh in runtime!